# Spring 3 autowiring by constructor - why does this code work?

Tags: spring, constructor, autowired, spring-3, constructor-injection

Spring version is 3.2

In Spring in Action, Third Edition, under 3.1.1. The four kinds of autowiring it is stated, that

> Autowiring by constructor shares the same limitations as byType. Spring won’t attempt to guess which bean to autowire when it finds multiple beans that match a constructor’s arguments. **Furthermore, if a class has multiple constructors, any of which can be satisfied by autowiring, Spring won’t attempt to guess which constructor to use**.

This last sentence is what makes me confused. I have the following bean definitions:

```
<bean id="independentBean" class="autowiring.IndependentBean" scope="prototype" />
<bean id="weirdBean" class="autowiring.WeirdBean" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="dependentBeanAutowiredByName" class="autowiring.DependentBean" autowire="byName" />
<bean id="dependentBeanAutowiredByType" class="autowiring.DependentBean" autowire="byType" />
<bean id="dependentBeanAutowiredByConstructor" class="autowiring.DependentBean" autowire="constructor" />
```

IndependentBean and WeirdBean are empty classes.

DepentendBean is defined as such:

```
package autowiring;

public class DependentBean {
    private IndependentBean independentBean;
    private IndependentBean anotherBean;
    private WeirdBean weirdBean;

    public DependentBean() {

    }

    public DependentBean(IndependentBean independentBean) {
        super();
        this.independentBean = independentBean;
    }

    public DependentBean(IndependentBean independentBean, IndependentBean anotherBean) {
        super();
        this.independentBean = independentBean;
        this.anotherBean = anotherBean;
    }

    public DependentBean(IndependentBean independentBean, IndependentBean anotherBean, WeirdBean weirdBean) {
        super();
        this.independentBean = independentBean;
        this.anotherBean = anotherBean;
        this.weirdBean = weirdBean;
    }

    // getters and setters for each field...

}
```

Now let us recall the statement in bold:

> Furthermore, if a class has multiple constructors, any of which can be satisfied by autowiring, Spring won’t attempt to guess which constructor to use.

According to this, I would have expected, that when trying to instantiate *dependentBeanAutowiredByConstructor*, Spring would throw an exception, not
knowing which of three constructors to use. But the code runs just fine.

So, what's up with this? Why is this code working? What is the erroneous circumstance
refered to in the above statement?

Comment: The constructor with the most arguments which can be satisfied by autowiring is picked - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/ConstructorResolver.java#L97 ... http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#AUTOWIRE_CONSTRUCTOR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is something that maybe the author knows best :-), but I'll share how I see it and how I understand it.

He says "*Spring won't attempt to guess*" meaning Spring won't just use `Math.random()` and get one of the three constructors randomly, just because all match. Which implies there is a rule Spring follows, it is something pre-determined and deterministic (on multiple attempts of the same test, there will be the same output).

Looking at `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`'s [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html):

> If multiple non-required constructors carry the annotation, they will be considered as candidates for autowiring. The constructor with the greatest number of dependencies that can be satisfied by matching beans in the Spring container will be chosen.

So, if all the three constructors match (which happens in your test), the one with the most arguments matched wins.

Comment: It might seem obvious that this mechanism is the same for xml based configuration, but: is this the same mechanism for xml based configuration? :) Or how can I find out if it is or not?

Comment: The only relevant reference for XML config is in here - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#AUTOWIRE_CONSTRUCTOR (for code reference check the link to GitHub in my comment to the question ;)).

Comment: I know what you mean :-), @Szűcs László. Let me see if I can find a proof in the source code.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/ConstructorResolver.java#L157) at this line the list of constructors is sorted. And the most relevant piece of code (actually, Java class comment) is [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AutowireUtils.java#L53) where it says that constructors are sorted by their "greediness". The ones that have most arguments are first in list.